# How to get CloudFront to cache locally for max-age

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control, response-headers

I have a custom origin that I am trying to cache locally. The default cache-control sends no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, and the pre and post checks are set to 0. I actually need the opposite. I need the browser to store, to cache, NOT to revalidate until my max age (24h / 86400s) is hit. There is private data being used and I don't need users seeing other user's data. I set up a response header policy to override cache-control with "private, max-age=86400" and I only get 200 HTTP responses (I am looking for a 304) and in x-cache I keep getting "miss from cloudfront" as well.

Some info about my setup:

- Protocol: Match Viewer
- SSL: TLSv1.1 (Custom cert that AWS handles)
- Methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE
- Unrestricted viewer access
- Legacy Cache: Headers(None), Query strings (ALL), Cookies (None)
- Object cache: Use origin headers
- Response Policy: Custom cache-control "private, max-age=86400"

The only other behaviors are using CachingDisabled on folders I don't want caching. I know this is likely just a bad config issue but I have no idea what's causing it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're looking for a `304`. That would only be used for revalidation, whereas you want the resource to be served from the browser cache, right? That will appear as a `200`, but with some indication that it came from the cache (depending on the browser developer tools). In any case, you should provide the full headers of a response that isn't behaving as you expect. Also indicate what browser or client you're using.

Comment: I have another custom origin that serves `304` so that's what i was basing my assessment on. I have been testing in both chrome and firefox. At the end of the day, If I can see an indication that it's using the local cache, and get it to Hit from CF instead of Miss then that'd be fine but I'm not seeing it in local storage. I'll link a set of headers here: [Working](https://i.ibb.co/Mn2wjyL/working-Headers.png) and [Miss](https://i.ibb.co/p3dmfPQ/miss-Headers.png)
Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You're sending `Cache-Control: max-age=0` in the request headers, which explicitly forbids a cached response. So, don't do that.

Comment: That same line is in the request that's working though.

Comment: No, that returns a `304`, which means it's revalidating with the server, not being served directly from the cache. The purpose of `max-age` is to indicate how long a resource can be served from the cache *without* revalidation. The `max-age=0` in your requests is preventing that, making the `max-age=259200` in the response irrelevant.

Comment: Even when I get the initial hit `200` from that I see `max-age=0` as well and it still becomes a `304` on refresh. The headers are [here](https://i.ibb.co/7gbM5D0/working-Headers2.png). I will still look into changing that in the request but I don't know if that's the real issue.